# Process, memory and network resource tracer

Tags: python, networking, memory, cpu-usage

I would like to try to make a process, memory and network resource tracer similar to the one that comes by default in ubuntu for any operating system. But being new in python I don't know how to get these values to be displayed (in principle by console, then I'll do them as graphics). Which library would be easier to do it with?

Comment: Are you asking about the right library to use for getting process, network, cpu data - or about a library that would allow you to present data in a console?

Comment: I ask for both, first for the library to take the data and for the library to generate the graphics so that it is the same as the one in linux

Comment: You can get some of the functionality you are after with the [psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil) module. To create a GUI, I highly recommend PyQt5. PySide2 is just as good, now, too. wxPython can do the job, as well.

Answer (score 0):

On linux, you could leverage the `/proc` filesystem to read the information you need for such a task.

the [`/proc`](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/proc-fs.html) filesystem is a window into the kernel with a lot of data on each process running. It is displayed as a virtual filesystem, meaning you can access all that info simply by reading and parsing files.

For instance,

```py
from pathlib import Path

proc = Path('/proc')

for proc in proc.iterdir():
    if not proc.name.isnumeric():
        continue # ignore directories that aren't processes

    pid = proc.name    
    cmdline = (proc / 'cmdline').read_text()
    print(f'PROCESS : {pid} : {cmdline}')
```

This will list all processes running, along with their commandline.

You have a lot of information you can gather in there.

more info on /proc [here](https://opensource.com/article/20/4/proc-filesystem)

Comment: My goal is to get the percentage of memory/network and active processes, not the names. Anyway thanks for showing me the proc in linux. Just out of curiosity, won't Windows have something similar?

Comment: proc has a lot more than just names, this is just an example. You can list open ports, see stats about process, etc. 

There is no equivalent on windows, not natively.